# How to call method with array input

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code containing a method to set and print values of an array:

```
int n;

// this is a method for get and set value of array
public static int[] avali(int n) { 

    System.out.println("insert number");

    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a1[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        a1[i] = num.nextInt();

    }

    return a1;
}

//method of inverse array
public void dovomi(int[] a) {

    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {

        System.out.println(a);
    }

 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("insert arr size: ");
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
    JavaApplication17 x = new JavaApplication17();
    x.avali(n.nextInt());
    x.dovomi(a1);

}
```

How can I call this method with the array as argument?
Why can't I access `a1` in this way?

Comment: error is in last line(x.dovomi(a1);)

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve). In it's current state, your question is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

your `dovomi` method and `main` have some mistakes you have to correct them to run your program:

second method should be `static` also `n` variable isn't defined inside scope of method instead you can use `a.length` to get size of array:

```
   public static void dovomi(int[] a) {

    for (int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {

        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
   }
```

`main` method also you have to define array and put the return array of `avali` method inside it to print the results of `dovomi` method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("insert arr size: ");
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = n.nextInt();
    int[] a1=new int[size];
    a1=avali(size);
    dovomi(a1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of return values.

Some methods don't return any values. They are marked `void`. And others do. They are marked with whatever type of value they return.

Examples of methods that do not return a value include `System.out.println()`, `dovomi`, `main` etc.

On the other hand, `n.nextInt` does return a value.

Can you see how `n.scan` is used differently from `System.out.println`?

```
x.avali(n.nextInt());
// vs
System.out.println("Hi");
```

`n.nextInt()` can be passed into a method as a parameter but `System.out.println` cannot. Why? Because `n.nextInt()` *returns a value*! Basically, methods that return a value can be used as values so you can pass them as parameters, assign them to variables, call other methods on them...

Now why can't you access `a1`?

Because `a1` is declared in the scope of `avali`, so you can't access it outside of `avali`. However, `a1` is returned by `avali`:

```
return a1;
```

So you can create a new variable and assign the return value of `avali` to it:

```
int[] a1 = x.avali(n.nextInt());
```

Now this line compiles!

```
x.dovomi(a1);
```